# Fatal error while loading class EWSType_FindItemType (php-ews)

Tags: php, class, class-design, exchangewebservices

I've never really had to play with classes but am looking to use [php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) on a page i'm working on atm.

my main file is calling the 5 "root" php files via include

```
include ("php-ews/ExchangeWebServices.php");
include ("php-ews/EWS_Exception.php");
include ("php-ews/EWSType.php");
include ("php-ews/NTLMSoapClient.php");
include ("php-ews/NTLMStream.php");
```

however these are complaining that files in there subfolders aren't included, in this case.

```
Fatal error: Class 'EWSType_FindItemType' not found in C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\mailtest.php on line 19
```

I have tried including the above file in the EWSType.php file and it then complains the next file isn't included. I have tried methods to include any .php in the folder and that isn't working.

I'm presuming I'm just going about loading a class wrong and was wondering if anyone could show me the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading classes manually, try `__autoload`ing them. That way you don't need to worry about keeping the list of includes. Autoloader will do it for you.
Should be easy enough, if class files are called the same as as classes themselves.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php
and  http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php for details

```
function ews_autoloader($className) {
  if($className != 'EWS_Exception') {
    $classPath = str_replace('_','/',$className);
  }
  if(file_exists("php-ews/{$classPath}.php") {
    include("php-ews/{$classPath}.php");
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('ews_autoloader');
```

Comment: unfortunately the files are not named appropriately for that function, the repository is located here for file names http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/source/browse/

Comment: @Xand94 : so I improved it a little ;)

Answer (score 0):

managed to put together a little bit of code to get the main folder files included.

```
$dir    = '/wamp/www/intranet/dashboard/php-ews/EWSType/';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files1 as $value) {
if(preg_match('/\.php$/i', $value)){
$inc = "php-ews/EWSType/";
$inc .= $value;
include ($inc);
}}
```